# Visualize commit activity statistics with Subclipse on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

Is there any Eclipse plug-in  that shows commit activity for [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) in terms on lines added/modified over time?

To make an example, it would very nice to have a graph visualization like the one provided by GitHub or BitBucket.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You really could not do this well from an Eclipse plugin as the information is not readily available.  The only way to get information like this is to get the history of the entire repository, and then produce a diff for each revision that you run through diffstats.  So realistically, this needs to be done by a backend service on the server that is doing this from a post-commit hook as each change is made.

Here is one tool that can do some of this:

https://code.google.com/p/svnplot/

It can do that initial expensive build of the data.  You would probably need to build in some kind of process to keep it maintained as new activity comes in as you would not want to constantly repeat the process from scratch every time you want to see the info.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I really believe in the "keep it simple" philosophy. I'll continue to look for an easier way of doing this...